# QSqlDatabase is the exec blocking?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

The documents said nothing about this.
I just wonder is the exec() call blocking or not?
Means, If I first create a table, then start a thread, in the thread I call a query to the table I just created.

Is it possible that the query will called before the table is actually built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `exec()` is blocking.  If you think about it, `exec()` has to block or you wouldn't be able to get results immediately after it returns.